# Show/hide a field depending on the value in another field (jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, css

On my website, I would like to make a field hidden if the value in the shopping cart is zero. And accordingly, vice versa: if the value in the basket of goods is greater than zero, then the field is visible to the user.

I've already implemented the function, but I'm having problems with the condition. Tell me how to correctly write the condition in this case?

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function updateTextFieldVisibility() {
      var textField = $('#grid-2');


      if ($('#grid-12-12-12').val() > 0) {
        textField.show();
      } else {
        textField.hide();
      }
    }

  });
</script>
```

Comment: While this is typically a simple interaction to achieve, [posting images of code is not acceptable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551); if you want us to help then please add your code to the question either as text or as a [code snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `$('#grid-12-12-12')` an HTML Element? You can check for it's value using `.text()` or `innerText` property

Also, consider using a "MutationObserver" to detect changes on elements as they happen (Instead of setInterval)

Here's an example:

```js
function isElementEmpty(element) {
  return +element.innerText
}

// Target element
const targetElement = document.getElementById('grid-12-12');

// Create a Mutation Observer instance
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (isElementEmpty(targetElement)) {
      // hide your element
      // ...
    } else {
      // show your element
      // ...
    }
  });
});


// Start observing the target element
observer.observe(targetElement, {
  childList: true
});

// To disconnect the observer when needed
// observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question. Unfortunately, your approach doesn't work: The element is always in show state

Comment: Probably the error is that the default amount in the cart is set to zero, that is, the field is not initially empty, but has a zero value.

Comment: first step, does *your* code work if you change `$('#grid-12-12-12').val() > 0` to `+$('#grid-12-12-12')[0].innerText > 0`  ?

Comment: Based on your hint I found the solution, thanks